# Parse error after deploying...dump.php on line 18

Tags: laravel

I deployed my application on server. As usually, I set `.env` file, than run `composer install (composer update)`, but I still get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable
>   (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/0/8/08d4b8c0-2888-4bba-9276-74df9dae3662/projects/example/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php
>   on line 18

Do you have any solution?

I tried various version of `php` and `Laravel`, but the error still remains.

composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.10",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "snowfire/beautymail": "dev-master",
        "ext-json": "*"
    },
```

Comment: Did you try `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` after setting `.env` file?

Comment: Yes, i tried it, but no change. I am not sure, what kind of problem should it be.

Comment: your local php version is not the same as the server you have deployed the application.

Comment: Yop, thank you. Mea culpa,I realized, that server php version is 5.5, upgrade to 7.3 solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. After changing my server PHP version to 7.4 it was fixed.